# Ubuntu 14.04 fails to boot - libpcre.so.3

Tags: 14.04, boot

I have done alot of searching and can't figure out how to fix my ubuntu installation.

I have a dual boot system with windows 7 (I can boot into windows fine).
When I try to boot ubuntu from grub as per usual, it now goes into kernel panic complaining

> error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This happened a while back and I haven't got around to fixing it until now. I can't remember what caused this (I assume a failed update). I can't use recovery mode as it gives the same issue nor any of the older kernels still installed.

I have tried booting into text mode or single mode, but it always fails the same way with the above error.

I have tried booting via a live usb stick and have managed to mount the root directories and chroot into them. However I can't do a

> sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade

due to the same issue. Even trying to do ls in a directory fails with the above error.

I would really appreciate any advice on how to get the ubuntu up and running again.

---

I have tried copying the `libpcre.so.3.13.1` from the live cd to the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` on the harddisk, and then linked it in the same folder to `libpcre.so.3`. Unfortuately that didn't work either. I can't find any useful log of the failed boot to share to help with the debugging.

Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide to help debug the issue.

Comment: Does `sudo ldconfig` help?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it gives the same shared library error

Comment: fisrt thing to do is to verify if the .so exist, the file should be in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` directory or you can use `find` utils to find the file. Follow this guide to restore and check your ld path. [GUIDE](http://codeyarns.com/2014/01/14/how-to-add-library-directory-to-ldconfig-cache/)

Comment: I have found the library in `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3` I made a link of it back to `/lib/` I then tried `sudo ldconfig`, but it still doesn't work. I however get a different error message

`root@ubuntu:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# sudo ldconfig
sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`

I'm guessing I have the 32bit version installed and that is screwing up the 64bit operating system

Comment: Remove the link of `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3` in `/lib`. After that boot into your live system, download http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pcre3/libpcre3_8.31-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb and extract the file via `dpkg -x libpcre3_8.31-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb foo` and copy the content of `foo` into your `/` of your system.

Comment: Doesn't anybody else thing it's odd that @Swifty is getting the same error on libpcre... for _everything_?  /sbin/ldconfig is statically linked, so there should be no problems running it.  I would be very wary of the system, as if some broken rootkit which needs the library to perform a lookup before a command is causing that warning.  May be a good time to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> Thank you A.B. That has fixed it!

Therefore I have converted my comment into an answer:

1. Remove the link of `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3` in `/lib`
2. Boot into your live system
3. Download and extract

   ```
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pcre3/libpcre3_8.31-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
   dpkg -x libpcre3_8.31-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb foo
   ```
4. Mount your root partition of your real system
5. Copy the content of `foo` into `/` of your real system